# How to click OK on messagebox?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I'm trying to develop a webbrowser application.
When my app clicks on a link, a messagebox pops up with OK and Cancel options. I have to click OK to continue. I tried every possible way to my knowledge with no success.

SendKeys did not work.

I believe if somehow I can switch to the message window, sendkeys might work.

How can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: What language and framework are you using, really? Is it ASP.NET? It surely isn't both C# and VB.NET.

Comment: Also, please show your code. Even if it doesn't work, it will help us figure out what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: This question does not make any sense.  Can you please reword it?  What do you mean when my app clicks on a link?  Do you mean the user?  What is the code behind those links?

Comment: it is a bot. auto clicks.

Answer (score 1):

Message Box is a UI element, there isn't an easy way to automate interacting with the message box. There is also the issue of using a Windows message box vs. using a JavaScript confirmation dialog.

Message Box is part of the server execution. It just so happen that in development your server and client are the same machine. So the Windows message box appears on the server (which is your local box.) if you were to deploy this to an actual server the message box would appear on the server, not the user's local machine. That' simply doesn't work for web development.

Now, you could use a JavaScript confirmation dialog. To do this you need to write/render JavaScript to the browser that will open a confirmation dialog when the body of the html is loaded. Not a good idea, but possible. Typically you want to avoid popups and dialogs when  a page loads.

So your best option is to either re-design the UI so a message box is not displayed or use a different route to execute the process and bypass the UI altogether.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using the WebBrowser control embedded in a WIndows form named Frm, you could try calling the Activate() and Focus() methods before using SendKeys...

```
Frm.Activate()
Frm.Focus()
SendKeys.SendWait("{Enter}")
```

That has worked for me.

Comment: thank you. this is a bot to reboot home dsl router. When "reboot" clicked, messagebox pops up, asking for confirmation. If somehow i can focus on the messagebox window, sendkeys would work but I don't know how to.